# AJAX responseText undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asmx, responsetext

Javascript code:

```
...............
...............
var cutid = $(th).attr("data-cutid");

var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Services/Cut.asmx/CheckCuts",
    data: "{'cuts':" + JSON.stringify(ListCuts) + ",'idCut':'" + cutid + "'}",
    dataType: "json"
}).responseText;

alert(request); // undefined
```

Function from web service:

```
    [WebMethod]        
    public string CheckCuts(List<CutM> cuts, Guid idCut)
    {
        return UtilCut.CheckCuts(cuts, idCut).ToString();
    }
```

The responseText is undefined. Why?

---

I added  *async: false* to ajax request.
Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called.

This code works:

```
function AjaxCheckCuts(ListCuts,cutid) 
{
    var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Services/Cut.asmx/CheckCuts",
    async: false,
    data: "{'cuts':" + JSON.stringify(ListCuts) + ",'idCut':'" + cutid + "'}",
    dataType: "json"       
    }).responseText;

    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(request);
    r = r.d;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the web service working correctly? Is it returning a HTTP 200? Can you see the data that is being returned using F12 tools or Fiddler?

`$.ajax()` is returning a deferred. Define a `done` method for it to execute when the async call completes. There is no `responseText` property, that's why it is returning a `undefined`.

Try this:

```
var cutid = $(th).attr("data-cutid");

var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Services/Cut.asmx/CheckCuts",
    data: "{'cuts':" + JSON.stringify(ListCuts) + ",'idCut':'" + cutid + "'}",
    dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```